# Why does the placeholder disappear and not appear?

Tags: html, placeholder

Placeholder disappears with focus and does not appear any more. It is necessary to do to appear.
When clicking on the text, the text should disappear, and when you click on the empty place of the form, the text should appear.

```
<form action="" class="form cons_form-gpu" id="cons_form">
        <p class="form__title">
             Получить бесплатную консультацию специалиста
        </p>
        <div class="form__field">
             <label for="name" class="form__label">
                Ваше имя
                <div class="form__inp-box">
                    <input type="text" name="cons_name" id="cons_name" class="form__input" required="" placeholder="Сергей">
                </div>
             </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__field">
             <label for="phone" class="form__label">
                Телефон
                <div class="form__inp-box">
                    <input type="text" name="cons_phone" id="cons_phone" class="form__input" required="" placeholder="+7 (___)___-__-__">
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form__field form__field_last">
            <label for="email" class="form__label">
                Эл. почта
                <div class="form__inp-box">
                    <input type="email" name="cons_email" id="cons_email" class="form__input" required="" placeholder="ivanov@mail.ru">
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
      <div class="agree_field" style="margin-top: 15px;font-size:12px"><input type="checkbox" name="agree1" id="agree" checked="checked">&nbsp;Даю согласие на обработку персональных данных
                                         в соответствии с <a href="Document-Agreement.pdf" target="_blank">Документом</a>
```

Получить консультацию

Comment: It's a browser feature, there is no way in which you can disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried in Firefox, text is displayed as long as no text is entered. So it works fine

Comment: It does not work for me. Placeholder disappears and does not appear any more.

Comment: I think there's nothing you can do about it. It's browser related.